# Finding the divisor of an unknown

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve this problem

> > A number when divided by a divisor leaves a remainder of 24. When twice the original number is divided by the same divisor, the remainder is 11. What is the value of the divisor?

I have established two relations here but dont know how to proceed , any suggestions would be appreciated .

$x= dq + 24  $ where d=divisor

$2x= dk + 11 $ where d=divisor

Comment: Shouldn't it be a different $q$ in the second equation? Maybe it's better to write it as $x \equiv 24 \bmod d$ and $2x \equiv 11 \bmod d$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you wrote, corrected:
$$\begin{align*}2x=&dk+11\\x=&dq+24\end{align*}$$
Substracting second eq. from first one and comparing the result with second eq.:
$$x=d(k-q)-13=dq+24\Longrightarrow d(k-2q)=37\Longrightarrow d=37$$
as $\,37\,$ is prime.

Comment: How did you assume that d=37 when $37$ is actually equally to  $d(k-2q)$ ?

Comment: I didn't "assume": since $\,d\mid 37\,$, then $\,d=1\,\,\,or\,\,\,d=37\,$ , right?

Comment: Yes that makes sense

Comment: Another way that I am trying to solve this - If I multiply equation (ii) with $2$ I get $2x=2dq+48$. After that I compare the two equations $2dq+48=dk+11$ which implies $d(2q-k) = -37$ .Does the negative sign here make my work wrong and invalidate it ?

Comment: Not at all: we work here with integer numbers, so positive or negative it doesn't usually mind (unless there's some specific requirement). It is customary to take positive divisors whenever possible, though.

Answer (score 3):

So $x \equiv 24 \bmod d$ and $2x \equiv 11 \bmod d$.  Subtracting the second from the first you get $$-24 \equiv -x \equiv (24 -11) = 13 \bmod d.$$ and therefore $d | (24+13) = 37$.  Note that $37$ is prime, so $d = 37$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the quotients won't be the same. Use $q_1$ and $q_2$. Another thing worth noting is that you can sub in $x$ from the first expression into the second. Once you've done that, the rest falls out immediately once you've gathered your $d$ terms on one side and the rest on the other--note that we can't have $d=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ d\!:\ x \equiv 24\:\Rightarrow\: 48\equiv 2x \equiv 11 \:\Rightarrow\: 37 \equiv 0,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:d\:|\:37$